# Probability mass function of a degenerate distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Wikipedia article ["degenerate distribution"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) states that "The probability mass function does not exist."  Is it really right? Why can't it be set as

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \quad x = x_0, \\
0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to disagree with wikipedia here....a pmf with $P(x_0)=1$ is totally fine. What is more problematic is trying to do this with a *continuous* r.v., in which case the degenerate *density* is a dirac delta function, which technically is not a function in the normal sense.

Comment: “More problematic" ... is using Dirac delta as PDF ill-defined?

Comment: @Problemaniac well, it has infinite density and so inherits all the problems associated with singular points.

Comment: In the meantime, you can see that Wikipedia has been corrected to agree with user76844.Note that the dirac delta is only heuristically defined as a pdf (equal to zero everywhere except at 0, where it is infinity).  Strictly speaking, this is not a pdf, and you will run into issues if you try to do any of the normal "pdf" things, like compute probabilities that X lies in some set.  Basically, changing the value of a function at one point (e.g. making it infinity) does not change an integral against the function.