# Density for degenerate distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Why is the density for degenerate distribution [defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/954944/473201) via the Dirac delta function, that is

$$\delta\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
+\infty, & x=x_{0}\\
0, & x\neq x_{0}
\end{cases}$$

instead of more intuitive

$$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1, & x=x_{0}\\
0, & x\neq x_{0}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: The distribution concentrated at one point has no *density*. What is your source for the strange statement in your question?

Comment: @Did, I provided the link to the source, don't you see it?

Comment: In reguards to your intuition, I suspect you are thinking that the probability **mass** of the singular point is $1$, which it is. $~$ *However*, what is the probability **density** at that point?

Comment: At this very link, did you read "In the meantime, you can see that Wikipedia has been corrected to agree with user76844.Note that the dirac delta is only heuristically defined as a pdf (equal to zero everywhere except at 0, where it is infinity). Strictly speaking, this is not a pdf, and you will run into issues if you try to do any of the normal "pdf" things, like compute probabilities that X lies in some set. Basically, changing the value of a function at one point (e.g. making it infinity) does not change an integral against the function" which seems spot on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability distribution function whose pdf is a delta function $\delta(x_0$ is the distribution for $X$  where the probability $P(X=x_0)$ is one (certainty).

Now consider things that you might do with a pdf $p(x)$; I will list two such things and compare your "more intuitive" f(x) to the delta function.

> 1) The probability that $x\leq y$ should be $\int_{t=-\infty}^y p(u) du$.

For the delta function $\delta(x-x_0)$, this works out fine, because the integral of  $\delta(x-x_0)$ over any interval including $x_0$ is one, and over any interval not including $x_0$ is zero.

For your $f(x)$ we are not so happy, since the stated integral is always zero.

> 2)The expectation value of $X$, which is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x p(x) dx$ should be $x_0$.

For the delta function $\delta(x-x_0)$, this works out fine, because the integral of  $x \delta(x-x_0)$ over any interval including $x_0$ is $x_0$.

For your $f(x)$ we are not so happy, since the expectation value integral is zero rather that $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the PDF of a random variable is defined. Note that the PDF of a random variable $X$, denoted by $f(x)$, is the derivative of the CDF, $F(x) = \Pr{(X \le x)}$.

In your case, $$F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}0, & \text{when }x<x_0; \\1, & \text{when } x\ge x_0.\end{matrix}\right.$$

Consequently, $f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x)=\delta(x-x_0)$, where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function $\left(\delta(0)=+\infty \right)$.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, for your answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In reguards to your intuition, I suspect you are thinking that the probability **mass** of the singular point is $1$, which *indeed* it is. 
 
However, what is the probability **density** at that point?

---

Technically, a discrete random variable *does not* actually have a probability density function, but we might *like* it to have *something* we could use with the same formulars built for continuous random variables.

Well, the *dirac delta* is a generalised function.   It is *defined* as a having zero value for any argument other than $0$, and yet *despite* being indefinite at zero, having a definite integral over the entire real interval; that is equal to $1$.   (This is often summarised as saying the value is $+\infty$ at $0$, although that is *somewhat* inaccurate.)

$$\delta(x) \simeq \begin{cases}0 &:& x\neq 0 \\ +\infty &:& x=0 \end{cases}~,~ \int_\Bbb R \delta (x)\mathrm d x = 1$$

Why, this is the very behaviour we require of a "probability *density* function" for a degerate random variable for it to be useable in a general sense.

So we *say* that the probability *density* function of a degenerate random variable is the shifted dirac delta function.

$$X\sim \delta(x_0) \iff f_X(x) ~{:= \delta(x-x_0) \\\simeq \begin{cases} +\infty &:& x=x_0\\ 0 &:& x\neq x_0\end{cases}}$$